# GameCenter participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome does not work

Tags: ios6, objective-c-blocks, game-center

I am bit in the unknown here and do not really know if this is anything wrong or not. I am trying to quit a turn-based game with the following code:

```
[match participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit
                       nextParticipants:[_match.participants objectAtIndex:1]
                            turnTimeout:GKTurnTimeoutDefault
                              matchData:match.matchData
                      completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                          if (error)
                              NSLog(@"Error while quitting match: %@", error.localizedFailureReason);
                      }];
```

But receives the following message when testing it:

> > Error while quitting match: (null)

This is the first time i am testing this and would need some message what is wrong, or if someone could hint me.

Cheers

**UPDATE**

I have search the internet (again) and found some code for IOS6 (http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=5244) that i am testing:

```
//   load all of the matches the player is currently a part of
[GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error)
{
    if (error) NSLog(@"Error loading matches: %@", error);

    //   create some placeholder match data
    NSString *matchString         = @"Deleting match";
    NSData *matchData            = [matchString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //   for each match
    for (GKTurnBasedMatch *match in matches)
    {
        //   log the id of the match
        NSLog(@"ID of match we are removing: %@", match.matchID);

        //   for each player we set their outcome to 'tied'
        for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *participant in match.participants)
            participant.matchOutcome      = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeTied;

        //   end the match
        [match endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:matchData completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
         {
             if (error) NSLog(@"Error ending the match: %@", error);

             //   and then remove it
             [match removeWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
              {
                  if (error) NSLog(@"Error removing match: %@", error);
              }];
         }];
    }
}];
```

It seems to work now but i get: GKErrorDomain Code=24, which seems to mean "GKErrorTurnBasedInvalidState = 24" and do not know what to do about it.

Comment: Any luck with this? I get the same error message.

Comment: I am afraid this was so long ago i do not remember how i fixed it, i did look in my code but could not find the fix.